# Plotting a Matrix in matlab with float elements

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have results of an experiment which is parameter optimization of support vector regression. I have the first three columns the parameters and the last column the MSE so I have about 24,646 X 4 matrix. I would like to get the parameters corresponding to the smallest MSE. How can I plot this on Matlab? the elements of the matrix are float numbers. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use second output of `min` to obtain the index of the minimum value in the fourth columns; and then use that to get the parameters:

```
[~, ind] = min(matrix(:,4));
params = matrix(ind,1:3);
```

Comment: It works perfect to get one value, but it would have been nice if I can plot it so that I get some idea about the sensitivity of the Algorithm. Is there anyway I can plot it? It also looks better for documentation. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you want. Perhaps it will be clearer if you edit the question and include a small example with an actual matrix

Comment: @user3612121 - What **exactly** do you want to plot?  Saying `it` doesn't mean anything to us.